# Different handling of .cpp and .h files?

Tags: c++, linker

C.h has

```
#ifndef UNTITLED3_C_H
#define UNTITLED3_C_H

class C {
 public:
  int F();
};

#endif //UNTITLED3_C_H
```

C-inl.h has

```
#ifndef UNTITLED3_C_INL_H
#define UNTITLED3_C_INL_H

#include "C.h"

int C::F() {
  return 1;
}

#endif //UNTITLED3_C_INL_H
```

main.cpp has

```
#include <iostream>
#include "C.h"


int main() {
  C c;
  std::cout << c.F() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now I compile them with the following command, but fails.

```
$ g++ main.cpp C-inl.h -o main
/tmp/ccVkEs1w.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `C::F()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I rename C-inl.h to C.cpp, the compilation works.

```
$ g++ main.cpp C.cpp -o main
$ ./main 
1
```

Why does file name make a difference?

When the files are `main.cpp, C.h, and C.cpp`, main.cpp only includes C.h, how does the content of C.cpp kick in? When the files are `main.cpp, C.h, and C-inl.h`, why doesn't the content kick in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class C {
 public:
  int F();
};
```

is a *declaration* of function `F()` as a member of class `C`.

```
int C::F() {
  return 1;
}
```

is the *definition* of that function.

If you include only `C.h` you have NOT the definition needed at `main()`. The compiler knows you want that 'F()' but doesn't have a reference for its definition (the "undefined reference" error message).

Now you rename `C-inl.h` to `C.cpp` and compile it. The trick is that `C.cpp` does include the `C.h` where the declaration is done. So everything is found, compiled and linked.

---

Hey, `C-inl.h` includes `C.h` and I told g++ to compile `C-inl.h`!!

Yeah, but [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) remarks how g++ takes the `.h` extension:

> file.h
>
> C, C++, Objective-C or Objective-C++ header file to be turned into a
>   **precompiled header** (default)

And you need that file to be handled as a `.cpp` file, not precompiled header.

Comment: C-inl.h does include C.h. Why doesn't compiler use it?

Answer (score 1):

By default, GCC determines what to do with each file you specify by looking at its extension.

From the [gcc(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc):

> file.**h**
>       C, C ++ , Objective-C or Objective-C ++ header file to be turned into a precompiled header.

So GCC assumes you want to use "C-inl.h" and "C.h" as precompiled headers.

You can override GCC's decision using the `-x` flag:

```
g++ main.cpp -x c++ C-inl.h -o main
```

I would recommend against doing this though.  C++ headers usually aren't compiled as separate compilation units, and doing so will make the next person to read you code very confused.  "C-inl.h" is *not* a header.  Name it what it really is: "C.cpp".

Comment: .h are to be turned into a precompiled header. .cpp must be preprocessed. Does "preprocessed" differ from "precompiled" in that compiler will look up definition in  **preprocessed** files?

Comment: Yes.  Preprocessing is what processes things like `#include` directives and `#define`d macros.  Precompiled headers are a mechanism for reducing compile times in large projects by avoiding re-compiling headers that are included in many compilation units.  98% of projects have no need for precompiled headers.

Comment: From [gcc precompiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html): *"A precompiled header file is searched for when #include is seen in the compilation"*